# Create a contingency table using pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm trying to create a general `pgfplotstable` style for displaying contingency tables (the below example is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)) of any sort but I am having trouble computing the totals for each row and column and adding them to the table on the fly.

I am aware that totaling up the row will involve creating a column and using `\pgfmathaccuma`, while the totals row should be done via `\pgfplotstablevertcat` but the particulars seem to be beyond me even after repeated reading of the documentation.

The solution should work for different tables with different number of columns/rows and different labels (though the totaled column and row can both be called Totals, they're just named differently here for reasons of clarity).

NB: I've included a hand-formatted table of the desired output below and my efforts so far (which use the actual table format I want to work with).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\section*{Desired output}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={%
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Handedness}\\            \cmidrule{2-3}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/Gender/.style={string type},
]{
    Gender       Right-handed Left-handed {Total by Gender}
    Male                   43           9               52
    Female                 44           4               48
    {Total by Handedness}  87          13              100
}

\section*{Current efforts}

\pgfplotstableread{
    Gender Right-handed Left-handed
    Male             43           9
    Female           44           4
}\chisquaredata

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
% Does not total up correctly
  create on use/{Total by Gender}/.style={
    create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{\pgfplotstablecolname}}},
  every head row/.style={%
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Handedness}\\
        \cmidrule{2-3}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/Gender/.style={string type},
  columns={Gender, Right-handed, Left-handed, {Total by Gender}},
]\chisquaredata

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `pgfplotstable`, it's much easier to add columns to tables than to add rows, so what I would suggest is to calculate the row sums first, then transpose the table, and then calculate the column sums (which are now rows, so we can just repeat the first action).

Here's a macro `\createcontingencytable{<table name>}{<first column name>}{<name for row sums>}{<name for column sums>}` that takes a table and the necessary names and spits out a `\contingencytable` macro that contains the table with the row and column sums.

For your example, you would say

```
\createcontingencytable{\chisquaredata}{Gender}{Total by Gender}{Total by Handedness}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={%
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Handedness}\\            \cmidrule{2-3}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/Gender/.style={string type},
  columns={Gender, Right-handed, Left-handed, {Total by Gender}},
]\contingencytable
```

to get

[image]

---

It also works with tables with more than two columns and rows:

```
\pgfplotstableread{
    Gender Right-handed Left-handed Ambidextrous
    Male             43           9           10
    Female           44           4            5
    Other            20           3            3
}\chisquaredata

\createcontingencytable{\chisquaredata}{Gender}{Total by Gender}{Total by Handedness}
```

[image]

---

Here's the complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcommand{\createcontingencytable}[4]{ %
% #1=table name
% #2=first column name
% #3=new row sum name
% #4=new column sum name
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={% In each row ... 
        \def\rowsum{0}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
        % ... loop over all columns, summing up the elements
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\rowsum{\rowsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
        }
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\rowsum
    }
]{#3}{#1}%
%
% Transpose the table, so we can repeat the summation step for the columns
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from={#2},input colnames to={#2}]{\intermediatetable}{#1}
%
% Sums for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \def\colsum{0}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
        }
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\colsum
    }
]{#4}\intermediatetable
%
% Transpose back to the original form
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=#2, input colnames to=#2]{\contingencytable}{\intermediatetable}
}
%

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    Gender Right-handed Left-handed Ambidextrous
    Male             43           9           10
    Female           44           4            5
    Other            20           3            3
}\chisquaredata

\createcontingencytable{\chisquaredata}{Gender}{Total by Gender}{Total by Handedness}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={%
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Handedness}\\            \cmidrule{2-4}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/Gender/.style={string type},
  columns={Gender, Right-handed, Left-handed, Ambidextrous, {Total by Gender}},
]\contingencytable


\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, I am well impressed. You just earned yourself a place in my thesis acknowledgements :-) I had transposed the table before for use in a bar chart, but I never thought of using that to add another row!

Comment: Great stuff. Minor comment: to use this inside the ``standalone`` class (which I find useful, I then insert tables as pdf objects), you could bring the ``\pgfplotstableread{``and  ``\createcontingencytable{`` commands just before ``begin{document}`` and not introduce any paragraph skip before ``\pgfplotstabletypeset[``, to avoid the insertion of blank spaces on the left of the table. :-)

Comment: @Jake, I tried to use your code for data that was in the thousands, but ran into integer limits. I tried to use ``\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}``, but it didn't help much and messed up with the totals. My workaround has been to use different units (dividing by 1000), but perhaps this is an interesting problem? Shall I ask a separate question?

Comment: @PatrickT: Yes, I think it would be a good idea to ask this as a new question including a minimal example.

Comment: @Jake, Thanks. Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418665/contingency-table-with-pgfplotstable-dealing-with-large-integers

Comment: @Jake, Thank you ever so much for setting a bounty on that question. It has attracted two great answers. :-)